# android two activity in one screen

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I want to implement one android activity that have a button inside of it. when this button is clicked , andother activity runs.
The second activity slides from left to right and get just 80% width of the screen , and the 20% remaining spaced should be filled by left side of first activity( first acitivity slides to right)
How can I implement it?
I think I should have two activity in one screen!

Comment: What you you need is a fragments.Have two fragments.

Comment: use `SlidingMenu` https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu, demo: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example

Comment: You could use [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) for this purpose. But it is deprecated since 13 api, so you should use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Android Does not support two activitis in single screen. insted of activities  u can use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: Could you please give me an example of implementation of what I want by fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Better you should use fragments .. Check here         http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html